# switch phone to data when wifi signal is weak

Tags: wi-fi

I am using Tasker.  How do i get my phone to turn wifi off when signal is low and turn data back on.  I also want it to check occasionally for a stronger signal.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that's not possible. When the data is on and when the device gets connected to Internet via WiFi, the data is stopped.

In Tasker, the `WiFi near` state has "Min. Activate Signal Level" with which you may monitor a WiFi for detecting the level. But if it falls below a point you cannot switch it off to connect to data.